# Anybody see a reason this mongoDB query should not be indexOnly: true?

Tags: mongodb

Anybody see a reason this mongoDB query should not be indexOnly: true?

I am hoping I am making a silly mistake.... I can't see what I am doing wrong and why this would not be an covered query.

I am using MongoDB 2.4.6

Here are steps to reproduce:

```
db.Test.insert({"_id" : ObjectId("5261ac33e4b070ca9e1480d1"), "date" : ISODate("2013-10-18T21:46:27.476Z"), "disabled" : false, "userHidden" : false, "postId" : NumberLong(103)})

db.Test.ensureIndex({ "postId" : 1, "userHidden" : 1, "disabled" : 1, "date" : -1}, {name: "findByPostId", sparse: true, unique: false})

db.Test.find( { $query: {postId: 103, userHidden: false, disabled: false}, $orderby: {date: -1}, $hint: "findByPostId", $explain: 1 }, {postId: 1, userHidden: 1, disabled: 1, date: 1 }  ).pretty()

{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor findByPostId",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "postId" : [
                    [
                            103,
                            103
                    ]
            ],
            "userHidden" : [
                    [
                            false,
                            false
                    ]
            ],
            "disabled" : [
                    [
                            false,
                            false
                    ]
            ],
            "date" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
```

Comment: you ned to omit the _id via _id:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Hopefully this will help someone else.

This was the problem:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries

> By default, MongoDB includes the _id field in the query result. So, if
>   the index does not include the _id field, then you must exclude the
>   _id field (i.e. _id: 0) from the query results.

By adding _id: 0 to the projection I get indexOnly true

```
> db.Test.find( { $query: {postId: 103, userHidden: false, disabled: false}, $orderby:     {date: -1}, $hint: "findByPostId", $explain: 1 }, {_id: 0, postId: 1, userHidden: 1, disabled: 1, date: 1 }  ).pretty()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor findByPostId",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 3,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 3,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : true,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "postId" : [
                    [
                            103,
                            103
                    ]
            ],
            "userHidden" : [
                    [
                            false,
                            false
                    ]
            ],
            "disabled" : [
                    [
                            false,
                            false
                    ]
            ],
            "date" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    }
```